# Magento: Error when attempting to load a product

Tags: php, magento, themes

I'm experiencing an issue with our site, as I am trying to rework the RWD theme to a custom design.

Just applying the unmodified theme results in the following error when you click on any product (the theme design applies fine, and site navigates properly until you click on a product).

```
Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media::isGalleryImageVisible(Array
(
    [0] => Varien_Object Object
        (
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [value_id] => 19905
                    [file] => /3/0/308-8_4cl.jpg
                    [label] => 
                    [position] => 0
                    [disabled] => 0
                    [label_default] => 
                    [position_default] => 0
                    [disabled_default] => 0
                    [url] => <website>/media/catalog/product/3/0/308-8_4cl.jpg
                    [id] => 19905
                    [path] => <server root>/media/catalog/product/3/0/308-8_4cl.jpg
                )

            [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
            [_origData:protected] => 
            [_idFieldName:protected] => 
            [_isDeleted:protected] => 
            [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
)

#0 <server root>/app/design/frontend/tlc_alpha/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml(48): Varien_Object->__call('isGalleryImageV...', Array)
#1 <server root>/app/design/frontend/tlc_alpha/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml(48): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media->isGalleryImageVisible(Object(Varien_Object))
#2 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(260): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#3 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(291): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->fetchView('frontend/tlc_al...')
#4 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(305): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->renderView()
#5 <server root>/app/code/local/Extendware/EWPageCache/Block/Override/Mage/Core/Template.php(14): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->_toHtml()
#6 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Extendware_EWPageCache_Block_Override_Mage_Core_Template->_toHtml()
#7 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('media', true)
#9 <server root>/app/design/frontend/tlc_alpha/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(53): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('media')
#10 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(260): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#11 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(291): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->fetchView('frontend/tlc_al...')
#12 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(305): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->renderView()
#13 <server root>/app/code/local/Extendware/EWPageCache/Block/Override/Mage/Core/Template.php(14): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->_toHtml()
#14 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Extendware_EWPageCache_Block_Override_Mage_Core_Template->_toHtml()
#15 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#17 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#19 <server root>/app/design/frontend/tlc_alpha/default/template/page/1column.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#20 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(260): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#21 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(291): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->fetchView('frontend/tlc_al...')
#22 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/ca/a0/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(305): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->renderView()
#23 <server root>/app/code/local/Extendware/EWPageCache/Block/Override/Mage/Core/Template.php(14): Mage_Core_Block_TemplateOverriddenClass->_toHtml()
#24 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Extendware_EWPageCache_Block_Override_Mage_Core_Template->_toHtml()
#25 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#26 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#27 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(91): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#28 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->defaultNoRouteAction()
#29 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/69/b9/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('defaultNoRoute')
#30 <server root>/app/code/community/ArtsOnIT/OfflineMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(46): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_StandardOverriddenClass->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#31 <server root>/var/cache/ew/files/52/17/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(191): ArtsOnIT_OfflineMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#32 <server root>/app/code/local/Extendware/EWPageCache/Controller/Override/Mage/Core/Varien/Front.php(17) : eval()'d code(17): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_FrontOverriddenClass->dispatch()
#33 <server root>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Extendware_EWPageCache_Controller_Override_Mage_Core_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#34 <server root>/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#35 <server root>/testsite/index.php(92): Mage::run('test', 'website')
#36 {main}
```

Can anyone give me any greatly appreciated pointers on what may be causing this? Other themes work fine, just not RWD and the one I modified from base RWD.

I'm on version 1.9.0.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media::isGalleryImageVisible is a method in 1.9.1 and later, while the production environment I am on is 1.9.0.1.

Comment: Will adding the method from 1.9.1 do the trick? I am facing the same problem currently.